# Bootstrap Multiselect - how to get values in php?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Bootstrap Multiselect plugin and I can't figure out how to get the values in php.
Here is my html

```
<select class="form-control" name="product" multiple>
 <option value="a">a</option>
 <option value="b">b</option>
 <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

here is the entire jquery block

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.home1')
  .find('[name="product"]')
    .multiselect({
     // Re-validate the multiselect field when it is changed
      onChange: function(element, checked) {
        $('#home1')
            .data('bootstrapValidator')                 // Get plugin instance
            .updateStatus('product', 'NOT_VALIDATED')  // Update field status
            .validateField('product');                 // and re-validate it
    }
  })
  .end()
  .bootstrapValidator({
  excluded: ':disabled',
message: 'This value is not valid',
live: 'disabled',
feedbackIcons: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
},
submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process-step1.php",
      data: $('.home1').serialize(),
      success: function(msg){   
          document.location.href = 'form.php';
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("error");
      }
    });//close ajax
},
fields: {
    product: {
        validators: {
            callback: {
                message: 'Please choose 1-5 products',
                callback: function(value, validator) {
                    // Get the selected options
                    var options = validator.getFieldElements('product').val();
                    return (options != null && options.length >= 1 && options.length <= 5);
                }
            }
        }
    }// product

} // end field
});// bootstrapValidator

}); //ready(function
```

In the javascript I can get the values by with this...

```
 var options = validator.getFieldElements('product').val();
 alert(options);
```

But how do I then send it to php in my ajax function

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
     url: "process-step1.php",
      data: $('.home1').serialize(),
      success: function(msg){        
         document.location.href = 'form.php';

      },
```

also once in php how do I get each value?

I tried

```
if(isset($_POST['product'])){

echo $_POST['product'];

  foreach ($_POST['product'] as $product){
      echo $product . ' was selected <br />';
  }
}
```

It made it into the if statement and the first echo statement returned the last of the selected items.  Then I got the following error when it went into the for statement.

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in     **/home3/haas12/public_html/bsi10/process-step1.php** on line **15**

I'm pretty sure I need to send the "options" array that the plugin uses to store but I don't know how.  I have other input items that are posting fine, but just not the product array.

I also tried making products an array using name="product[]" but then that breaks the plugin code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML is correct (`<form class="home1"...>`), in PHP they should exist as `$_POST['product']` which would be an array.

You haven't said what you want to do with the values, so here are a couple of examples.

You can dump them to the page to check they are there, though your JS is redirecting afterwards so you won't see the output in your console unless you prevent that to debug.

```
print_r($_POST['product']);
```

or iterate through them (again, you won't see this with that redirect in place)

```
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $product){
    echo $product . ' was selected <br />';
}
```

If the user doesn't have to select any you should check that there are any there first

```
if (isset($_POST['product'])) { /* do stuff here */ }
```